# Is there a way to distribute Google Calendar gadgets?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-gadget, igoogle

I needed a gadget for Google Calendar so I wrote it; I'd like to offer it to the public for free.

However, after going around in circles through Google help on publishing gadgets, it seems that [iGoogle directory](http://www.google.com/ig/directory) is only for iGoogle gadgets. Although my gadget works on iGoogle by redirecting user to Google Calendar, iGoogle users don't really need something like this. My gadget makes sense only inside Google Calendar itself.

Is there a way to offer my gadget to the public without people needing to add "Add any gadget by URL" gadget and paste URL to my gadget? Something like "add gadget to iGoogle" button, if there is no official directory of Google Calendar gadgets...

Answer (score 0):

Try Google Marketplace - http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/

Comment: I've seen the marketplace, and somehow I don't think that's what I need. When I find a Google Calendar product and "Add it now" it asks for Google Apps domain; it's not geared towards individual users. Also: "There is a non-refundable $100 fee for your first listing. There is no charge for subsequent listings." So I don't get "add to your Google Calendar" button, and even if that worked, I get to pay $100 to distribute essentially free app...